Can we use prism in fluorescence microscope instead of dichroic mirror?
For the light path outlined here, if we use a prism instead of a dichroic mirror, the excitation light can also pass through the prism, but the emission filter can block the excitation wavelength if the transmission of filter is indicated as on Thorlab. Would that be a problem to see the fluorescence and why?
